# Why does my process not disassociate from tty?

Tags: posix

I written a tool to share a tmux sessions across Linux user IDs such that a master user leads a session and observers have read-only access to the session(s).  There are two parts:

- A script to start a named session
- A C program to run setuid with the master uid by the observer uid

The problem is that if the interactive shell that starts the observer process exits, the observer is killed.  I have tried to avoid this by properly daemonizing the child process, but it doesn't work (see code).  I also experimented unsuccessgully with SIG_IGN, then removed that code.

Here is the code:

Part 1, the script to start the master session:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                             

sessionName=${1:-shared}                                                        
me=`id -ru`                                                                     
socket=/tmp/tms-$me-shared                                                      

tmux -S $socket new-session -s $sessionName                                     
# Use companion setuid pgm to start slaves...                                   
# tmux-slave [sessionName]
```

Part 2 is the C code for the observer that runs setuid as the master:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *alist[] = { "xterm","-e","/usr/bin/tmux", 0 };
    int me = geteuid();
    char tmuxCmd[200];
    char sessionName[10] = "shared";
    if (argc > 1) {
            strncpy(sessionName,argv[1],9);
            sessionName[10] = '\0';
    }
    sprintf(tmuxCmd,"/usr/bin/tmux -S /tmp/tms-%d-shared att -t %s -r",me,sessionName);
    alist[2] = tmuxCmd;

    printf("\nppid/pid/sid/pgid: %d/%d/%d/%d\n",getppid(),getpid(),getsid(0),getpgrp());
    int fc;
    if (!(fc = fork())) { // child
        int sid = setsid(); // put child in independent session
        setpgrp();
        printf("New ppid/pid/session/pgrp is %d/%d/%d/%d\n",getppid(),getpid(),sid,getpgrp());
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
        if (fork() > 0) exit(0); // spawn child in new session
        execv("/usr/bin/xterm",alist);
        printf("Failed to invoke tmux in xterm\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // parent
    printf("Child PID from first fork(): %d\n",fc);
    if (fc == -1) {
        printf("fork() failed for slave\n");
        exit(-2);
    }
    printf("Slave spawned from %d\n",getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

compile:

```
bill@port:~/Desktop/u/src$ cc -o tmux-slave tmux-slave.c; chmod u+s tmux-slave
```

and so to run this:

```
bill@port:~/Desktop$ tmux-share cherry # master session
```

and:

```
cindy@port:~$ /home/bill/Desktop/u/src/tmux-slave cherry
```

then, everything is fine until cindy exits shell.  It hangs.  Ctl-C causes exit, but then child (observer xterm/tmux) dies.  Like a process started without using nohup.  I thought setsid() would take care of this.  Apparently not.

Eh?

Comment: Follow up: the code does not exhibit the problem if both the master and observer are the same uid.  FWIW!

Comment: Follow, follow up... the problem does not appear to be related to the code.  In my test cases, I was relying on ssh tunneling.  Thus, killing the invoking shell destroyed the tunnel required to keep the xterm alive.  Duh.  Close this issue.  Apologies to anyone who wasted time reading the code.  But you are welcom to use the idea with tmux!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - trying to mark this closed.

There is no issue in the code.  The problem was in the environment.  I was relying on a ssh tunnel which was destroyed when the invoking shell was closed.  Silly me.

So how do I mark this closed?

Comment: You can delete question itself, in fact.